# How to capture highlighted text and pass the text to database in Django?

Tags: django

I am writing a Django app to analyze the sentiment of content.
Below are aims I would like to achieve:

At Template:
I would like to highlight some text in the content and define the sentiment (e.g. positive / negative) nature of the text.

Database:
highlighted text and sentiment will be input.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Django question as the execution takes place in the browser. However this *should* be possible with JavaScript.

You can bind event listeners to text areas/inputs/specific text divs in JavaScript. I don't believe there is any highlight specific events. However you can bind `mouseDown` and `mouseUp` listeners to the text. Then decide based on the target/timing/whatever if the cursor was moved over text.

Then you need to extract this text based on the event listeners/mouse positioning and send an ajax request to your server for processing.

It will probably require a good bit of tweaking, but should be possible.